# How to merge SQL results?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

There is lot of questions on merging SQL results. Here is my case that has two different SQL results.

```
userID   Car
1        Ford
2        Honda
3        Toyota
```

```
userID   Color
1        Red
2        Silver
3        White
```

Is there a way to merge both of the above into the follows in SQL:

```
userID   Car      Color
1        Ford     Red
2        Honda    Silver
3        Toyota   White
```

Comment: This can be done with a simple JOIN.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `join`:

```
select ca.user_id, ca.car, co.color
from cars ca join
     colors co
     on ca.user_id = co.user_id;
```